# Writing a generic HTTP request in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, http

I am making an app that creates multiple HTTP requests to different APIs, and would like to abstract the "sending" and "getting" portion of the data into a utility function that can be exported. It should be async. So far, I have created the following, but it won't work since `request.end()` needs to be declared somewhere, and I'm stuck here. Thanks!

**Note**: the resulting data should be able to be easily returned to some other function on order to do other work with it later on.

```
exports.handleHttpRequests = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = http.request(url, response => {
            let chunks = [];
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                let body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
                resolve(body);
            })
        })
    }).then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `request-promise` module already does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, though I would like to implement this in vanilla nodejs only, both to reduce dependencies and also as a learning experience.

Comment: Well, then go study the code of the `request` or `request-promise` modules that have already written the code for you.  It's generally silly in node.js to rewrite code that has already been written and fully tested for you (the code is all on Github).  To me that's 75% of the reason for using node.js so that you can build on top of the hundreds of thousands of fully tested and debugged modules that already solved problems for you.

Comment: FYI, there's a pretty complete example (just without the promise wrapper) [in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) and it shows you where the `request.end()` goes.

Comment: I trust in your judgement. I'll look into request-promise and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you already done all, just call request.end() inside your new Promise callback & also handle error . And do what you want to do with resolve ,reject.

```
    exports.handleHttpRequests = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = http.request(url, res => {
      let chunks = [];
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        let body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
        resolve(body);
      })

    });
//handling error
    request.on('error', (e) => {
      reject('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
//here you have to put request.end()
    request.end();
  })
};
```

Comment: You can remove `.then(data => {
    return data;
  });` as that is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah sure it's not needed